# how to pass values using @Input()

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnVIN.png)
How should I do so that my card can get data from another file?

**OneProcessItemComponent.ts**

```
export class OneProcessItemComponent {
  @Input() item = processItem;
}
```

**OneProcessItemComponent.html**

```
<div class="process__item">
  <div class="process__wrap">
    <img src="{{ item.image }}" alt="process" class="process__img">
    <div class="process__item-title">{{ item.title }}</div>
    <div class="process__item-subtitle">{{ item.subtitle }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**processItem.ts**

```
export const processItem: IProcessItem[] = [
  {
    title: `Buy Now`,
    subtitle: `Lock in a buy order now at the current
    spot price.`,
    image: `../../../../../../../assets/img/process-1.svg`,
  },
```

Comment: This is not very clear. `@Input()` is used to receive data from a parent component. In your case you're initializing the `item` property with `processItem` (imported from `processItem.ts`) but that value will be overriden with the value passed from the parent (because that's what `@Input()` is used for). What issue are you actually facing here?

Comment: @lbsn I added a photo with errors

Comment: try get a minimum working demo on a link(stackblitz or something), so that someone can see what you are trying to achieve in the whole code.
As @Ibsn said, @Input() is used to receive data from parent component down to child.

Answer (score 0):

Your compilation errors occur because your component template expects `item` to be a single `IProcessItem` but `processItem` is an *array* of `IProcessItem`s

You can fix it by removing the square brackets around the definition of `processItem`

Also you wouldn't normally assign a variable to an input like that, rather you would assign it in the parent template.

```
<app-one-process-item [item]="processItem"><app-one-process-item>
```

The idea being you can pass whatever item in you want, and it is not constrained to the specific one you currently have in your component.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
// app component
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>

// hello component
@Input() name: string;
```

// Example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x77xcs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

`*ngFor` required for `IProcessItem[]`. (Try to recreate the whole scenario.)

---

**app.component.ts**

```
import { IProcessItem, processItem } from "./processItem";

@Component({...})

export class AppComponent {
  public processItem: IProcessItem[] = processItem;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-one-process-item [item]="processItem"><app-one-process-item>
```

---

**processItem.ts**

```
export interface IProcessItem {
    title: string;
    subtitle: string;
    image: string
}

export const processItem: IProcessItem[] = [{
    title: `Buy Now`,
    subtitle: `Lock in a buy order now at the current
      spot price.`,
    image: `../../../../../../../assets/img/process-1.svg`,
}];
```

---

**OneProcessItemComponent.ts**

```
import { IProcessItem } from "../processItem";

@Component({...})
export class CombineThreeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() item: IProcessItem[];

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```

---

**OneProcessItemComponent.html**

```
<div class="process__item" *ngFor="let data of item">
    <div class="process__wrap">
        <img src="{{ data.image }}" alt="process" class="process__img">
        <div class="process__item-title">{{ data.title }}</div>
        <div class="process__item-subtitle">{{ data.subtitle }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Output -

[image]